# Icon in the statusbar

Tags: android

How do I add a widget to your belt battery notification?

I mean the icon in the statusbar.

Can you give me an example?

Comment: next time, search this with google: http://bit.ly/yqLFDS

Answer (score 0):

You have to using status bar notifications :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html